# CAS server connection through c3p0 to SQL Server 2012 AUTHENTICATION_FAILED with good credentials

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-security, single-sign-on, cas

I installed a CAS server release 4.0 for SSO against certain Spring security applications and, probably in the future, .net and php applications. I'm deploying it on a Tomcat 8.0 on my local machine running on JDK 7 by Oracle.

I tested the connection and authentication through the CAS login page (both from the server's page and from the Spring application) using the default `org.jasig.cas.authentication.AcceptUsersAuthenticationHandler` mechanism. Everything is working fine in that case. Next step, connect it to an SQL Server 2012 database.

I created the table users as pointed out in the documentation ([Database Authentication](http://jasig.github.io/cas/4.0.x/installation/Database-Authentication.html)). I also added the following dependencies through maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
  <artifactId>cas-server-support-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
  <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
  <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Then I included the corresponding authentication handler in the *deployerConfigContext.xml*

```
<bean id="passwordEncoder"
      class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.DefaultPasswordEncoder"
      c:encodingAlgorithm="MD5"
      p:characterEncoding="UTF-8" />

<bean id="primaryAuthenticationHandler"
      class="org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.QueryDatabaseAuthenticationHandler"
      p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
      p:passwordEncoder-ref="passwordEncoder"
      p:sql="select password from users where username=? and active=1" />
```

In the same file I define datasource(just omitted hostname, port, user and password in here):

```
<bean id="dataSource"
      class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
      p:driverClass="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
      p:jdbcUrl="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<my_host>:<my_port>/CentralSecurity"
      p:user="<my_user>"
      p:password="<my_password>"
      p:initialPoolSize="6"
      p:minPoolSize="6"
      p:maxPoolSize="18"
      p:maxIdleTimeExcessConnections="120"
      p:checkoutTimeout="10000"
      p:acquireIncrement="6"
      p:acquireRetryAttempts="5"
      p:acquireRetryDelay="2000"
      p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="30"
      p:preferredTestQuery="select 1" />
```

Database user I'm using is administrator of the database an has full access. I go to the login page of my CAS Server and enter an username and password that exist as a record in the users table. CAS connects to the database but authentication is said to have failed without further information. I don't get any information about why the authentication is failling. The trace of the CAS server only says the following and there's no further log information in the tomcat server logs:

```
2015-04-13 13:21:10,072 INFO [org.jasig.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager] - QueryDatabaseAuthenticationHandler failed authenticating joe+password
2015-04-13 13:21:10,072 INFO [com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: joe+password
WHAT: supplied credentials: [joe+password]
ACTION: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Mon Apr 13 13:21:10 CEST 2015
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
=============================================================


2015-04-13 13:21:10,073 INFO [com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: joe+password
WHAT: 1 errors, 0 successes
ACTION: TICKET_GRANTING_TICKET_NOT_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Mon Apr 13 13:21:10 CEST 2015
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
=============================================================`
```

I also tried with the other AuthenticationHandlers for Database connection specified in the documentation with no luck at all. If I change the table name from the query the same log says that the error was because it couldn't find the table in the database (which is true) so that seems to indicate the database is being reached. I've tested this like a million times, the password I'm providing is the right one (I have changed it even to be sure of this).

The only thing I'm not very sure of is the MD5 password encoder. I'm using the login screen provided by CAS. Is is encoding the password? I have done nothing to encrypt the database password for the moment either (that I'll have to change but it's still unclear if we'll be able to use LDAP. As a POC I want to keep it simple, local and intranet with this configuration)

Anyone who faced same or simillar difficulties? It should be quite straightforward I guess but it's driving me nuts :-)

Comment: UPDATE: I encoded password data using MD5 algorithm and I am now getting some kind of useful feedback from CAS Server. I'm getting the message  'principal' cannot be null.'. It seems the problem is when resolving the principal after successfully performing authentication against the database. I haven't changed any configuration regarding this, it's the clean install as is. I see that there are other questions regarding this topic so I'll keep updating any progress I make in case someone finds himself in my situation. Any help still appreciated though

Comment: UPDATE. I finally got to see a more detailed trace of the problem: `java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.SimplePrincipal.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V from class org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.SearchModeSearchDatabaseAuthenticationHandler` They're all starndard delivered libraries. Can't figure aout what's going on.

Comment: UPDATE: I installed a mySQL server to make tests with a different DDBB. I get the exact same error. It is related to the AuthenticationHandler as I am using the PrincipalResolver in the default in memory AuthenticationHandler and it's working ok. I can't figure out what the problem with the AuthenticationHandler is.

Comment: I finally solved it. I created a custom class copying the content of SearchModeSearchDatabaseAuthenticationHandler from github. I just tried it without further modifications (my intend was to trace and put extra exception handling to determine the problem) and it started working. I guess that what was being downloaded through the maven repository was not up to date somehow. Not a clue about why or how this was a problem.